# Is there a way to use bools with strings? I want to search for a word in a string, and if it's there, output the meaning

Tags: c++, string, conditional-statements

I am very new to coding and this is my first language, C++. I have an assignment that is really confusing.

The assignment wants me to search the user input of one line for slang words. Ex: TMI or BFF. However, I don't know how to use conditional expressions to do this, and I have tried if-else statements but they end up reading all the statements instead of each one that applies. The code always comes up with a problem for the conditional expression because I honestly have no clue how to use them for strings in this manner. Any help is appreciated!

(Slang terms are required to be capitalized to be read.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string userInput;
int textSlang = '0';

cout << "Welcome to the Text Message Decoder!" << endl;
cout << "WARNING! Slang is case-sensitive. Please make sure all slang is fully capitalized!" << endl;
cout << "Enter a single line text message: " << endl;

getline(cin, userInput);

cout << "You entered: " << userInput << endl;

if (textSlang == string::npos) {
   cout << "Error" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("IDK" ))) {
cout << "IDK: I don't know" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("TTYL" ))) {
cout << "TTYL: Talk to you later" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("TMI" ))) {
cout << "TMI: Too much information" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("JK" ))) {
cout << "JK: Just kidding" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("BFF" ))) {
cout << "BFF: Best friends forever" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("LOL" ))) {
cout << "LOL: Laugh out loud" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("TYSM" ))) {
cout << "TYSM: Thank you so much" << endl;
}

else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("OMG" ))) {
cout << "OMG: Oh my god" << endl;
}

cout << "END." << endl;

//textSlang = userInput.find("TTYL");
//textSlang = userInput.find("TMI");
//textSlang = userInput.find("JK");
//textSlang = userInput.find("BFF");
//textSlang = userInput.find("LOL");
//textSlang = userInput.find("TYSM");
//textSlang = userInput.find("OMG");


}
```

Comment: Fun fact:  `int textSlang = '0';` actually sets `textSlang` to 48 (which is the numeric value of the ASCII character `0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("IDK" ))) {
cout << "IDK: I don't know" << endl;
}
```

assigns `textSlang` to `0` IFF `userInput` begins with `IDK`. In *all other cases* it assigns some value *other* than `0`.

And *all* `int` values other that `0` evaluate to true.

You want:

```
else if ((textSlang = userInput.find("IDK" )) != string::npos) {
  cout << "IDK: I don't know" << endl;
}
```